# single line LDAP query that enumerates users from a group within a supergroup

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a scheme that looks like this:

1. Users exist like UserA, UserB, UserC.
2. Groups exist like OverGroup, SubGroup.
3. OverGroup automatically adds new users like UserA, UserB, etc. to its membership.
4. SubGroup I created myself. I have set OverGroup to be a member of SubGroup.

I want to be able to one-line query SubGroup and retrieve not OverGroup, i.e.:

```
Values:  
CN=OverGroup,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com
```

but the full enumeration of the actual Users (User A, B, C) within OverGroup, i.e.:

```
Values:  
CN=UserA,OU=OtherOU,DC=example,DC=com
CN=UserB,OU=OtherOU,DC=example,DC=com
CN=UserC,OU=OtherOU,DC=example,DC=com
```

Is there a one-liner LDAP filter that could retrieve this? (It will be put into the ExternalAuth configuration 'ldap' section in a Request Tracker instance. Pretty sure I can only do this with one query the ExternalAuth module can understand.)

Everything I try does not work, and from my reading, it does not seem possible to enumerate a list of users within a group that is a member of another group with any one-line query. Thoughts?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Active Directory has a special search filter option that allows it to filter through chained objects, like nested groups. The capability is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Here is an example of how to retrieve all users in a group, including nested groups:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0}))
```

where `{0}` is the DN of the parent group.

Comment: It works, although the query is slow as hell (~5-10 seconds)

Comment: Since it has to recurse through and return the entire subtree once it's identified the root, the performance of the query is expected to scale with the depth / breadth of the tree. It's equivalent to an SQL "Connect By" query, and, in fact, may translate into that under the covers. That said, something that functions slowly is usually better than something that doesn't function at all. If you've a faster solution, please do share so that all may benefit.

Comment: If you set the base/root as a particular user DN, it's fast, but obviously only checks whether that user is a member.

Comment: Just FYI: it is very fast for me in a very large organization.

Comment: I think it's important to note this does not display all members of the group.  For instance, Foreign Security Principals may not be returned, unless I'm mistaken

Comment: what is `1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941` ?

Answer (score 7):

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=MPV_BedPlacement,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=CCHCS,DC=CCHCS,DC=LDAP))
```

You have to add the full DN for the group and no curly braces.