# PHP ldap_search in Active Directory subgroups

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have an AD group ***Students*** that has group ***ClassA*** as its member.

User ***John*** in an AD group ***ClassA***:

```
Students --> ClassA --> John
```

I am running *ldap_search()* on the ***Students*** group looking for ***John***:

```
$filter = '(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=John) (memberof=CN=Students,OU=Groups,OU=Units,dc=ad,dc=aaa,dc=bbb))';

$result = ldap_search($ldap_resource, $ldap_domain, $filter);
```

The search turns out unsuccessful.

However, if I move the user directly under ***Students***:

```
Students --> John
Students --> ClassA
```

The user is being successfully found.

How do I search recursively in subgroups?

Comment: possible duplicate of [single line LDAP query that enumerates users from a group within a supergroup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143665/single-line-ldap-query-that-enumerates-users-from-a-group-within-a-supergroup)

Comment: @DaveBennett you are righ, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!